# how to solve this two limit tasks

Tags: limits

Hello i stumbled across this two limits task and i cant find an answer to them:

> 1. Find the limit depending on the parameter $A$
>      $$\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt[4]{x^2 + x + 1} \right) \cdot x^A\right)$$

I tried by multipliying with
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt[4]{x^2 + x + 1}}{\sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt[4]{x^2 + x + 1}}$$
which equals 1 and then
$$\frac{x+1 + \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}}{x+1 + \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}}$$ so i can get rid off roots in denominators but i got tangled up,

> 2. $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left((x+1) - \sqrt[3]{x^3 + x^2} \right)$$

lim in both tasks goes to +infinity

Comment: Hey! Your question is unreadable. Please try to edit it using MathJax. I tried but found some parts that are a bit cryptic

Comment: The limit is $\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt[4]{x^2 + x +1}x^A$??? and $x \rightarrow ??$

Comment: lim goes to + infinity  ,thank you for mentioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2 we have $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left((x+1) - \sqrt[3]{x^3 + x^2} \right)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^2+3x+1}{(x+1)^2+(x+1)\sqrt[3]{x^3 + x^2} +\sqrt[3]{(x^3 + x^2)^2}}$.
Now you can factor $x^2$ both in the numerator and the denominator and see that the limit is $\frac{2}{3}$.The first limit can be done similarly.
Note: What I used was that $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$,$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you but how did you come from (x+1) - 3th root(xpow3 + xpow2) to lim 2xpow2+3x + 1 /(x+1)pow2 + (x+1) 3th root(xpow3+xpow2) + 3th root((xpow3 + xpow2)pow2)

Comment: I used the formula I mentioned in the note. In your case you have $a=x+1$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2}$.

Comment: ok i understand it tnx

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of Taylor expansion. Substitute $x=1/t$, so $t\to0^+$ and the limit can be rewritten as
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+t}-\sqrt[4]{1+t+t^2}}{t^{A+1/2}}
$$
The numerator can be rewritten as
$$
1+\frac{1}{2}t-1-\frac{1}{4}{t}+o(t)
$$
So the limit is $1/2$ when $A+1/2=1$. What if $A>-1/2$ or $A<-1/2$?

The second limit can be computed similarly.

Comment: thank you but what does the o(t) represents?

Comment: @Petar $o(t)$ is an unnamed function with the property that $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{o(t)}{t}=0$.